# mathtex on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to revive an old Wiki (mediawiki 1.24.2) I had running for the last several years. The equations have been done in mathtex. Which used to be a real pain to install and deal with. So I paid for someone else who provided a service.

Well long story short, that server is no longer up and running. Now I need to install mathtex on my own server which is running Ubuntu 16.04 on an 8 core AMD.

I used `sudo apt-get install mathtex` which completed without error or warning. But when I go to the domain /cgi-bin/mathtex.cgi with the example latex code I get an error `The requested URL /cgi-bin/mathtex.cgi was not found on this server.`.

I can't find mathtex.cgi on my server (don't know where to look and no help from Google). I'm wondering if the issue isn't in my apache virtual host files.

Answer (score 1):

This is what´aptitude search says:

```
# aptitude search mediawiki
p   dico-module-mediawiki                              - RFC 2229 compliant modular dictionary server (mediawiki modu
p   git-mediawiki                                      - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (MediaWi
p   libhtml-wikiconverter-mediawiki-perl               - Perl module to add MediaWiki markup support to HTML::WikiCon
p   libmediawiki-api-perl                              - Perl interface to the MediaWiki API
p   libmediawiki1                                      - KDE C++ interface for MediaWiki based web services (runtime)
p   libparse-mediawikidump-perl                        - Perl module to parse MediaWiki dump files
p   libtext-mediawikiformat-perl                       - module that converts Mediawiki markup into other text format
p   libwww-mediawiki-client-perl                       - simple CVS-like interface for editing MediaWiki websites
p   mediawiki2latex                                    - Loads pages from MediaWiki and converts to LaTeX and PDF
p   mediawiki2latexguipyqt                             - lightweight GUI for mediawiki2latex
```

This are the same results as of Ubuntu 14.04. There you should find the right libs.